# A positive measurable and improper integrable function is integrable

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,+\infty)$ a positive measurable function. Suppose $f$ is improper integrable. Show that $f$ is integrable.

> Take a row $x_{n} \rightarrow \infty$ and a row $y_{n}\rightarrow -\infty$ We know that:
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{x_{n}}^{y_{n}} {f} {d\lambda}$ exists. We can write this as: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{1}_{[x_{n},y_{n}]}f $. We can use now the monotone convergence theorem. Is this OK? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct if you assume that both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are monotone. You could actually fix them: $x_n = -n$, $y_n = n$.

Comment: But we know that $f$ is improper integrable. So we have to go to $+\infty $ and$  -\infty$ at a indepent way. Or am I wrong?

Comment: We *can* but not *have to*.

Comment: OK, so we know that it works for every row to $+\infty$ and every row to $-\infty$ (monotone rows) because $f$ is improper integrable. So we can take that row , to apply the monotone convergence theorem. Is this OK?

Comment: yes, it is correct.